# csExWB automatic click on link on webpage

Tags: c#, click

how do i automate link clicking on a webpage?

I tried:

```
csExWB.cEXWB cEXWB1 =new csExWB.cEXWB();
cEXWB1.navigate2("www.url.com");
cEXWB1.AutomationTask_PerformClickLink("my_link_by_id");
```

I have form presenting the web page, but nothing happens (that is - i stay on original page, no link is pressed).

i also tried:

```
 cEXWB1.AutomationTask_NamedLinkScrollIntoView("my_link_by_id");
```

still no good... What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the underlying html for the document you are crawling. In this case, I would specifically be looking for javascript acting on the link or defining the link.

Generally referred to as "mousetraps", the practice looks for evidence of a human reading the page after it is properly rendered. This can be as simple as updating the link URL when the body element, or some other parent element of your link, gets its first ONENTER, ONOVER, etc event. Dropdown menus tend to have this "feature" quite often. Other times, and more commonly, the page loads dynamically...and the link url hasn't been written yet.